# How do I use the sorted key function call in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of strings that represents playing cards. Ranks can be

A23456789TJQK

Here is my list

```
# L2
['5', '6', '7', 'A', 'K']
```

And I'm trying to make a function to call with the key in the sorted function to return the card rank numerical values in order. So here is my function:

```
def sortYo():
   myDict = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, 'T': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10}
```

And here is my call:

```
L4 = sorted(L2, key = sortYo())
```

But my L4 ends up the same:

```
# L4
['5', '6', '7', 'A', 'K']
```

Why isn't my sortYo() function changing the values? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations
import sys


myList = sys.argv
myList.pop(0)
Suits = ['H', 'S', 'D', 'C']
Nums = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
SuitsTwo = {'♥': 'H', '♦': 'D', '♣': 'C', '♠': 'S'}
print(myList)
L1 = [] # Suits
L2 = [] # Ranks
L3 = [i for i in myList[0]] # Cut
for i in myList:
   for x in i:
      if x in SuitsTwo:
         L1.append(SuitsTwo[x])
      elif x in Suits:
         L1.append(x)
      else:
         L2.append(x)

print('L1:'
print(L1)
print('L2:')
print(L2)
print('L3:')
print(L3)
score = 0
# straight
sC = 0
myDict = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9\
': 9, 'T': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10}

L4 = sorted(L2, key = lambda x: myDict.get(x,11))
print('L4')
print(L4)

#RUN
python3 as13.py AS 5H 6C 7S KH
['AS', '5H', '6C', '7S', 'KH']
L1:
['S', 'H', 'C', 'S', 'H']
L2:
['A', '5', '6', '7', 'K']
L3:
['A', 'S']
L4
['A', '5', '6', '7', 'K']
0
```

Comment: ... Because you don't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a lambda function for the sorting key:

```
myDict = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, 
          '9': 9, 'T': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10}

L4 = sorted(L2, key=lambda x: myDict.get(x, 11))
```

This will sort by the values associated to each key in `myDict`.  It will also place any value in `L2` that is not in the keys of `myDict` at the end of the sorted list by assigning a default value of `11` to unknown keys.

If you don't have to worry about items in `L2` that are not in the keys of `myDict`, you can also use:

```
L4 = sorted(L2, key=myDict.get)
```

Comment: Remove the lambda, just let key=myDict.get

Comment: Good point, but you can't include the default value.  I will add it.

Comment: I dont think you should expect a missing value, we are talking about cards, we know all the possible values

Comment: I tried this method and the other one but I'm still not getting anything happening. Should I edit the question to show what's happening?

Comment: Yes, please do so.

Comment: @Coder117 well it worked, the list was already sorted, remember your ace is worth 1

Comment: Ohh I thought it was returning integers XD Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(..., key='A23...JQK'.index)
```

Comment: Fortunately there aren't any (10 uses "T" instead).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks. I'm still not getting anything happening though. You mentioned in another comment that I'm not returning anything. What am I supposed to return in the sortYo() function? Am I supposed to return myDict?

Comment: You're supposed to return the desired key for the value that gets passed to it.

Comment: I tried returning myDict[i] but I'm still not getting anything. Any ideas?